# How to ignore analysing a whole module in android lint

Tags: android, lint

I implemented an open source module in my android project. I want to ignore the lint analyzation for this module. I studied the other questions and tried to create lint xml in my project root directory. Here it is my lint xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
<issue id="all">
    <ignore path="open_source_module"/>
</issue>
</lint>
```

I tried to change the path structure like : **/open_source_module, **/open_source_module/src...

But they didn't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: you can use go through custom scopes mentioned in android lint documentation.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.

Comment: where did you place your lint.xml file?

Comment: Hi Sagar, my structure project is app_v2/app (app module), app_v2/open_source_module (open source module), app_v2/common (common module). I had put lint xml in app_v2 directory

Comment: Hi Umair, I read again the document and followed it to create my scope to exclude the module, it works, 

Answer (score -1):

add this lines in your module level build.gradle file :

```
android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
   }
```